# Sql 2005 CLR Integration - Is Dynamic Assembly Loading supported?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I have a static class which loads a .NET assembly dynamically (using `Assembly.LoadFile` method)
I get the following error message:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MySQLCLRUDFFunction": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyClassName' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed
```

.

When I try assign CAS security using this declaration

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
```

I instead get this exception

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MySQLCLRUDFFunction": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyClassName' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
```

Note: I have given my SQL Server service account "Full Access" to my dynamic assemly file on disk. I copied my dyamic assembly using syntax:

```
create Assembly TestAssembly
    From 'C:\MyTestAssembly.dll';
--Alter Assembly to copy dynamic assembly file
Alter Assembly TestAssembly add file from 'C:\mydynamicassembly.dll';
```

After turning `TRUSTWORTHY ON` and setting `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` I now get this exception

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MySQLCLRUDFFunction": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyClassName' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: LoadFrom(), LoadFile(), Load(byte[]) and LoadModule() have been disabled by the host.
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, dynamic assembly loading is completely disallowed by SQL Server - even under unsafe.  The only way for Assembly.Load calls to succeed is if the assembly is already loaded in the database via CREATE ASSEMBLY or in the GAC and on the [list of supported ("blessed") assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx).  There is another post on this on the [sqlclr blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlclr/archive/2006/10/18/dynamic-assembly-loading.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question now, but I have recently found a way to achieve what you want. When you try and using `Assembly.Load(...)` in a SQL CLR hosted assembly, it will explicitly fail, this is by design, even with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`. This is to ensure the stability of the database server.

The technique to loading your dynamic assemblies, is to register them first and then resolve the type using `Type.GetType(...)` passing in the fully qualified type name (including assembly version information.

Here are the steps:

1.Compile the type, and finalise on disk (i.e. do not create in-memory assemblies). The `CompilerResults` type will have a `CompiledAssembly` property and `PathToCompiledAssembly` property. Use the latter as accessing the `CompiledAssembly` property will attempt to use `Assembly.Load`.

2.Using the path, I call a stored procedure from my code (using `new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true")`) which I pass in the name of the assembly (which I have predetermined) and the compiled assembly path:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE re.CreateAssembly
    @name VARCHAR(100),
    @path VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)
    SET @sql = N'CREATE ASSEMBLY [' + @name + '] AUTHORIZATION [DatabaseUser] FROM ''' + @path + ''' WITH PERMISSION_SET + SAFE';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

3.Using your predetermined name, you can use `Type.GetType(...)`, e.g.:

```
string typeName = "MyCompiledAssembly.MyClass, MyCompiledAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL";
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

When the SQLCLR attempts to resolve the type, it should find it, because in step 2 you've already registered the assembly with Sql Server.

Comment: Interesting approach. Just out of curiosity: when would you need to use something like this? What situations require dynamic loading and not knowing ahead of time what to load?

Comment: @srutzky At the time of writing, .NET 3.5 was still hanging round - I had back ported my OOS project RazorEngine to .NET 3.5 so I could install it into Sql Server for use on a database-level error reporting mechanism. You could feed errors into a set of tables in SQL (as the DB was the common denominator between every other system), and it would trigger a throttled error email. Razor was used to control the email templating. As RazorEngine generates unique DLLs for each template, they had to be loaded to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got the PERMISSION_SET set to SAFE when you did CREATE ASSEMBLY (this will be the default if you didn't specify it). You'll need to change it to EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE if you want to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx

Comment: @Greg Beech and @DenNukem - thanks for your thoughts. 
I tried make the permission changes and still got the last exception - I have edited the original question with the details. And the exception seems to indicate that dynamic loading of assemblies is disabled...

Comment: Hmmm that sounds pretty conclusive to me; if SQL Server has explicitly disabled it then it sounds like you aren't going to be able to dynamically load assemblies. I didn't know that was a restriction even in UNSAFE mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was one the developers @ Microsoft who worked on SQL-CLR integration, so I may be able to help.

To achieve what you want you need to do two things:

1. Mark data base as TRUSTWORTHY
2. Mark assembly as UNSAFE (database must be trustworthy)
3. The account under which SQL Server runs must have permissions to access the file on the the file system. Often times the file is on a network share but SQL Server is run under local account that has no permission to access network, so this is often a problem. SQL Express in itse default installation does not have rights to C:.

Note that doing all those things has several negative side-effects:

1. serious security implications - you are effectively ceding control over the instance to the code in unsafe assembly as it can now use raw pointers to access/change anything in the engine.
2. Stability - you're also ceding stability guarantees for the same reasons.
3. Portability and disaster recovery - if you database has to move elsewhere for load-balancing or is restored from backup after machine failure you will not have the mydynamicassembly.dll on the new machine.

If at all possible, consider redesigning your app so that all needed assemblies are pre-loaded into the database itself.

[EDIT: if none of the above helps it best to ask on MSDN forums].